# Appending object instead of reference

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to add multiple div's within a div inside for loop:

```
  for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
      $('#parent').append('<div class="child"></div>");
  }
```

This works perfectly, but when I do:

```
  for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
      var child = $('<div/>', { class: 'child' });
      $("#parent").append(child);
  }
```

I get very strange results, I believe it's because using the second method, the reference instead of the object itself is passed. How can I pass just pure object, no reference, to the append method? thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by strange

Comment: your code looks just fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/po6uxpLf/1/ - if the child object is created within the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [cloning](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
$("#parent").append(child.clone());
```

You are appending the same object over and over, so nothing happens. It's just taking the element and putting it back in the same place.

The clone makes sure it's a fresh object which is a copy of the original.

Out of above link:

> Consider the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>   <div class="hello">Hello</div>
>   <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> ...
>   given the code:
>
> `$( ".hello" ).appendTo( ".goodbye" );`
>
> The resulting DOM structure
>   would be:
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>   <div class="goodbye">
>     Goodbye
>     <div class="hello">Hello</div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> To prevent this and instead create a copy of the element, you could write the following:
>
> `$( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" );`
>
> This would produce:
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>   <div class="hello">Hello</div>
>   <div class="goodbye">
>     Goodbye
>     <div class="hello">Hello</div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```